# How to resolve "Parameter validation failed" error I get when uploading pandas dataframe to s3 bucket as a parquet using boto3?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, dataframe, amazon-s3, boto3

I am following a tutorial on udemy where I am trying to upload pandas dataframe to s3 bucket as a parquet using boto3. I used BytesIO to convert dataframe to parquet and tried uploading it to my s3 bucket which I made accessible to public.

On execution I encounter an error :

```
Parameter validation failed:
Missing required parameter in input: "Key"
Unknown parameter in input: "key", must be one of: ACL, Body, Bucket, CacheControl, ContentDisposition, ContentEncoding, ContentLanguage, ContentLength, ContentMD5, ContentType, ChecksumAlgorithm, ChecksumCRC32, ChecksumCRC32C, ChecksumSHA1, ChecksumSHA256, Expires, GrantFullControl, GrantRead, GrantReadACP, GrantWriteACP, Key, Metadata, ServerSideEncryption, StorageClass, WebsiteRedirectLocation, SSECustomerAlgorithm, SSECustomerKey, SSECustomerKeyMD5, SSEKMSKeyId, SSEKMSEncryptionContext, BucketKeyEnabled, RequestPayer, Tagging, ObjectLockMode, ObjectLockRetainUntilDate, ObjectLockLegalHoldStatus, ExpectedBucketOwner
```

I am currently on macOS monterey 12.6.1

Here is the code, df_all is a dataframe :

```
key = 'xetra_daily_report_' + datetime.today().strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S") + '.parquet'

out_buffer = BytesIO()
df_all.to_parquet(out_buffer, index = False)
bucket_target = s3.Bucket('name-bucket')
bucket_target.put_object(Body = out_buffer.getvalue(), key = key)
```

Following is my bucket policy :

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::name-bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::name-bucket/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::name-bucket/+"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`key` should be `Key` (python is case sensitive):

```
bucket_target.put_object(Body = out_buffer.getvalue(), Key = key)
```

Comment: I'm so embarresed right now :') I was stuck here for a day now. 
P.S this works perfect for me. thanks a lot @Marcin